# Copy and paste excel workbook, object variable or with block not set

Tags: excel, vba

Not sure why I cant copy and paste "Nap" sheet to "Sheet7".  The file paths are correct, however, the transfer values part responded with "object variable or with block not set"

```vb
Sub Copy and Paste Workbook
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("___")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("___")

'Now, transfer values from x to y:
**y.Sheets("Sheet7").Range("A1").Value = x.Sheets("Nap").Range("F3:AA12")**

End Sub
```

Comment: Is either of `y` or `x` open already before you run the macro?

Comment: you can't assign a multi-cell range to the value of a single cell

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a multi-cell range to the value of a single cell.

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub Copy and Paste Workbook
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("___")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("___")

'Now, transfer values from x to y:
With x.Sheets("Nap").Range("F3:AA12")
    y.Sheets("Sheet7").Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.count).Value = .Value
End With
   

End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like `y.Sheets("Sheet7").Range("A1").Value = x.Sheets("Nap").Range("F3:AA12")` should throw an Object variable or with variable not set though... can't reproduce that on my end. Though I agree that it is quite incorrect.